# Require some JavaScript's libraries conditionally in the View of Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, node-modules

I have installed socket.io using `npm install socket.io --save` and I want to include its JavaScript in some views. I don't want to load it in all pages using mix. I have tried:

```
@section('btm')
<script src="{{ asset('js/socket.io.js') }}"></script>
```

However, it points to missing file `404 error` I also tried:

```
@section('btm')
    <script src="{{ asset('/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js') }}"></script>
```

But the same 404 error too.

Answer (score 0):

As usual node_modules stored root of project. so you should specify that. 
You can follow this:

```
<script src="{{url('/').'/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js'}}"></script>
```